# Probability Density Function of a Natural Logarithm plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot the Probability Density Function of a Natural Logarithm in R.

As is the picture :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPja2.png)

On the page from which the image comes, it is done for Python

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/the-probability-density-function-of-a-natural-logarithm-b1506ea9f894

I want to get such  graph in R, so please help me.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput` and code you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the plot in the link:

```
curve(2*exp(x)/sqrt(2*pi)*exp((-1/2)*exp(x)^2), -8, 8, ylab = "PDF")
```

However, note that this is the log-tranformed PDF of a standard [half-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) distribution. The PDF of a log-transformed standard normal distribution isn't defined on the real number line. Logarithms of negative numbers result in imaginary numbers.